# How to create a one-button back command in a file explorer in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to know what command I should use on a button to go back to the previous folder in the file explorer I made using vb.net.
Example: The folder starts with the path in C: \ Test and if I enter a folder named test1 the path will be in C: \ Test \ test1 and when I click the back button it goes to the previous folder it would be in C: \ Test and so with whatever path I enter and click the back button it will always return to the previous folder.
Remembering that I can have larger folder paths like C: \ Test \ test2 \ documents \ images and when I click the back button it goes to C: \ Test \ test2 \ documents and when it clicks again it goes to C: \ Test \ test2, and so on.

Help me with this, it only needs this command to complete the project. Please help me?

[image: File explorer design images]

```
 Public Class Form1
    Dim path As String
    Dim nextPath As String
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        On Error Resume Next
        path = TextBox1.Text
        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(path)) Then

            explorer.Clear()

            For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
                explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

            Next
            For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
                explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
            Next
        Else
            MsgBox("Its A File")
            'or user
            'pocess.Start(path) // to open the file
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        On Error Resume Next
        path = "C:\Test"
        For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
            explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

        Next
        For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
            explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_ItemSelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles explorer.ItemSelectionChanged
        nextPath = path + "\" + e.Item.Text

    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles explorer.SelectedIndexChanged


    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles explorer.MouseDoubleClick
        On Error Resume Next
        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(nextPath)) Then
            path = nextPath
            explorer.Clear()
            TextBox1.Text = path
            For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
                explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

            Next
            For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
                explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
            Next
        Else

            Process.Start(path & "\" & explorer.SelectedItems(0).Text)
        End If

    End Sub


    Private Sub BtnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click

    End Sub


End Class
```

Here is the part that goes back button:

```
 Private Sub BtnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: `Directory.GetParent(path).FullName`

Comment: Please get rid of `On Error Resume Next`. You are just swallowing errors instead of catching and correcting them. We have error handling in .net with `Try...Catch...Finally....End Try`.

Comment: Got it. I put the code and already gave error to put it, but as suggested in visual studio the code will look like this: Dim unused = Directory.GetParent (path) .FullName and when I run the program and click back nothing happens, nor does it give error and does not return to the previous folder. So it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igor my friend i see you want to finish this project so bad i will help you :) try this:

```
Private Sub BtnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
   try
        nextpath = path.substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\"))
        path = nextpath
        explorer.Clear()
        TextBox1.Text = path
        For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
            explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

        Next
        For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
            explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
        Next
   catch ex as exception
        msgbox(ex.message)
   end try
End Sub
```

for each time you want to visit a directory using explorer don't write this code every time just create a sub like so:

```
private sub go()
   try
        path = nextpath
        explorer.Clear()
        TextBox1.Text = path
        For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories(path)
            explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 2)

        Next
        For Each i In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path)
            explorer.Items.Add(i.Substring(i.LastIndexOf("\") + 1), ImageList1.Images.Count() - 1)
        Next
   catch ex as exception
        msgbox(ex.message)
   end try
end sub

Private Sub BtnBack_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
        nextpath = path.substring(0, path.LastIndexOf("\"))
        go()
End Sub
```

here's how the new path will look like: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nv1vAP